Query is not working properly in my Mern app
I'm building a lead data website using the MERN stack. Users can filter data based on various criteria like country, city, job title, seniority, industries, department, email type, and more (over 10 filtering options in total). They can choose any field or a combination of fields to filter the data. I've set a limit of 25 records per request to keep the responses manageable.
Currently, I've indexed all fields (country, city, job title, etc.) individually, and when using a single filter, the data retrieval is fast and efficient. However, when users apply multiple filters, the performance drops significantly—either the data is not filtered correctly, or the results take a very long time to load.
I experimented with compound indexing, which improves performance for specific combinations of filters. However, since users can apply filters in any random combination, I'm struggling to figure out the best approach to optimize query performance across all potential filter combinations.
here is my filtering backend code
if (Array.isArray(filters.countries)) {
        addCondition(
          "_source.person_location_country",
          "$in",
          filters.countries
        );
      }

      if (Array.isArray(excludedFilters.countries)) {
        addExclusionCondition(
          "_source.person_location_country",
          "$nin",
          excludedFilters.countries
        );
      }

      // job title
      if (Array.isArray(filters.jobTitle)) {
        addCondition("_source.person_title", "$in", filters.jobTitle);
      }

      if (Array.isArray(excludedFilters.jobTitle)) {
        addExclusionCondition(
          "_source.person_title",
          "$nin",
          excludedFilters.jobTitle
        );
      }

      // seniority
      if (Array.isArray(filters.seniority)) {
        addCondition(
          "_source.person_seniority",
          "$in",
          filters.seniority.map((s) => s.toLowerCase())
        );
      }

      if (Array.isArray(excludedFilters.seniority)) {
        addExclusionCondition(
          "_source.person_seniority",
          "$nin",
          excludedFilters.seniority.map((s) => s.toLowerCase())
        );
      }

// Apply all conditions
      if (conditions.length > 0) {
        query.$and = conditions;
      }

      if (exclusionConditions.length > 0) {
        query.$and = [...(query.$and || []), ...exclusionConditions];
      }

results = await Contacts_V5.find({
          _id: { $in: savedItemsIds },
          ...query,
        })
          .skip((page - 1) * limit)
          .limit(limit)
          .exec();

res.status(200).json({
        results
      });

My question is:

How can I optimize the filtering queries in MongoDB when users can apply any combination of filters?
Should I be using compound indexes, or is there another approach that could handle such flexible filtering more efficiently?

Any advice or best practices for indexing and optimizing query performance in this scenario would be greatly appreciated!

Have you checked out wildcard index?

"However, when users apply multiple filters ...
the data is not filtered correctly ..." what does not filtered correctly mean?

@user20042973
Right now , when i choose multiple field to filter, Its loading for a long time and sometimes it is in an infinite loading state. Once i filtered data by country Afghanistan, I get 12k data and then i add another filter with job title of Teacher, it went to loading and I waited 20 mins then cancel

@ray
I did not.
is it good to go?
because I already have 60 Milions+ data and 10-11 filtering fields.

@AliSadainTanvir You need to try it out and measure the performance yourself. One of the starting points would be replicating the environment on another testing environment and build the index on it. Examine the explain plan like this to see how it goes.
